# How to add months to a date in yyyymm format

Tags: oracle11g

I have two columns in my table one is having a date in `yyyymm` format and other column has some integer values between 1 to 50. How can I add these two fields and get a date value?

For example: `201402 + 12` should give me `201502` as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

I assume you don't really have a `DATE` column but a `varchar` column that stores a month specification in the format `yyyymm`.

If you want to make use of Oracle's date arithmetic you first need to convert this "month" into a real date.

Something like this:

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date('201402', 'yyyymm'), 12), 'yyyymm')
from dual;
```

You will need to replace the character literal `'201402'` with a reference to your column.